# Pandas append data in postgreSQL with { } in string

Tags: python, pandas, database, string, postgresql

I'm try to create a executable that gets data by scrapping a website and then insert it into a local database.

I'm using SQLalchemy and psycopg2

E.g:

```
products = soup.find_all('div', 'product-info')
        time.sleep(1.3)
        data = {'Product Name': ["test"], 'Product Price': ["price"]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.head()
        for i in products:
            justText = i.text
            pos = justText.find('R$')
            numbers = re.findall(r'(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', justText)
            # print(numbers)
            df.loc[justText[:pos]] = [justText[:pos],numbers]
            print('Preço do Produto: ', numbers, 'Nome do Produto: ', justText[:pos])
        df.to_sql('data', con=conn, if_exists='append',index=False)
        conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        conn.autocommit = True
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql1 = '''select * from data;'''
        cursor.execute(sql1)
        for i in cursor.fetchall():
            print(i)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

This is the output:

```
Preço do Produto:  ['$3.291'] Nome do Produto:  Namorado · Arroz branco tipo 1
Preço do Produto:  ['$9.79900'] Nome do Produto:  Vitaliv · Óleo de soja
Preço do Produto:  ['$7.29500'] Nome do Produto:  Fritz Frida · Lentilha tipo 1 Premiun
Preço do Produto:  ['$4.09'] Nome do Produto:  Da Barra · Açúcar refinado
Preço do Produto:  ['$4.25'] Nome do Produto:  União · Açúcar refinado
Preço do Produto:  ['$7.29'] Nome do Produto:  Namorado · Feijão preto tipo 1
Preço do Produto:  ['$9.85900'] Nome do Produto:  Concórdia · Óleo de soja tipo 1
Preço do Produto:  ['$18.90500'] Nome do Produto:  Melitta · Café torrado e moído tradicional
Preço do Produto:  ['$5.591'] Nome do Produto:  Tio João · Arroz integral longo-fino tipo 1
Preço do Produto:  ['$17.90'] Nome do Produto:  3 Corações · Café torrado e moído tradicional
```

And then my values are inserted with '{' and '}' in the database. I want to know what should I do to prevent this from happening since this will break other parts of my project.

[database values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTaSx.png)

Comment: I do not see any '{' or '}' in the output. What is the question?

Comment: Output looks to be lists saved in data frame column. Try saving first item, `[0]`, of `numbers` list. Also, why use pandas for this especially since you loop to assign rows. Simply loop to execute insert statements with psycopg2. Plus, you don't use `pd.read_sql` to read back data but use cursor loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [parameterized query](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) with only `psycopg2` without `pandas` data frame build or `sqlalchemy` insert action. Be sure to extract secular *numbers* value and not list which `findall` returns.

```py
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql = 'INSERT INTO data ("Product Name", "Product Price") VALUES (%s, %s)'

# PARSE WEB CONTENT
products = soup.find_all('div', 'product-info')
time.sleep(1.3)

for i in products:
    justText = i.text
    pos = justText.find('R$')
    numbers = re.findall(
         r'(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', 
         justText
    )
     
    print(
        'Preço do Produto: ', numbers[0], 
        'Nome do Produto: ', justText[:pos]
    )

    # BIND TUPLE OF PARAMETERS
    cur.execute(sql, (numbers[0], justText[:pos]))
    conn.commit()
```

Alternatively, with [**`cursor.executemany`**](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) via list comprehension:

```py
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql = 'INSERT INTO data ("Product Name", "Product Price") VALUES (%s, %s)'

def extract_values(i):
    justText = i.text
    pos = justText.find('R$')
    numbers = re.findall(
         r'(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', 
         justText
    )

    return (number[0], justText)

# PARSE WEB CONTENT
products = soup.find_all('div', 'product-info')
time.sleep(1.3)

# BUILD LIST OF TUPLES
vals = [extract_values(p) for p in products]

# BIND LIST OF TUPLE PARAMETERS
cur.executemany(sql, vals)
conn.commit()
```

If you really need a pandas data frame for analytical purposes, then read parsed data without sqlalchemy:

```py
sql = "SELECT * FROM data"
product_data = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

**Note**: Please adjust any Python object names or Postgres table/column names. Ideally, avoid spaces in column names and very generic table identifiers like *data*. Also, save price data as number data types without currency symbols. Store currency in different column.